# Feature Selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I tried to do recursive feature selection in scikit learn with following code.

```
from sklearn import datasets, svm
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
import numpy as np

input_file_iris = "/home/anuradha/Project/NSL_KDD_master/Modified/iris.csv"
dataset = np.loadtxt(input_file_iris, delimiter=",")
X = dataset[:,0:4]
y = dataset[:,4]

estimator= svm.OneClassSVM(nu=0.1, kernel="rbf", gamma=0.1)

selector = RFE(estimator,3, step=1)
selector = selector.fit(X,y)
```

But it gives following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/anuradha/PycharmProjects/LearnPython/Scikit-learn/univariate.py", line 30, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py", line 131, in fit
return self._fit(X, y)


File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py", line 182, in _fit



raise RuntimeError('The classifier does not expose '
RuntimeError: The classifier does not expose "coef_" or 
"feature_importances_" attributes
```

Please some one can help me to solve this or guide me to another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your kernel to **linear** and your code would work.

Besides, `svm.OneClassSVM` is used for unsupervised outlier detection. Are you sure that you want to use it as estimator? Or perhaps you want to use `svm.SVC()`. Look the following link for documentation.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html

Lastly, iris data set is already available in sklearn. You have imported the `sklearn.datasets`. So you can simply load iris as:

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
```

Comment: Yeah thank you, I got it. But I need to know one thing, why we cannot use svm.OneClassSVM as estimator?

Comment: REF is used to eliminate insignificant features and to do so you need to use a **supervised learning** estimator. It starts with all features, fits the estimator to the data, then assigns weights to the features based on their importance. Then it eliminates the least important feature and does this  untill the number of remaining features in the data set is equal to n_features. In contrast, OneClassSVM is an **unsupervised** technique to identify outliers in the observations. In other words it is used to eliminate outliers in **observations** rather than eliminating insignificant **features**.